# How do we import question data from HTML files to QnA Maker?

Tags: azure, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

We have html files placed within folders. Structure of the directory is as below.

[image]
Is is possible by any way to import these html in Q&A maker?

Answer (score 1):

As far I know you cannot import HTML file directly to QNA maker. But as QNA maker supports excel file (In excel, HTML and RTF files are supported). So from excel you can import your HTML file.

[image]

for more details please have a look here [QNA maker file and URL data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/concepts/data-sources-supported#file-and-url-data-types)

Hope it will help you.